# Plugging a solr index into django app using haystack

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I have some data in a mysql database and its indexed through the solr admin app. I want to expose this data as facets in a django app. I explored ajax solr and it seems to be a very good solution for integrating solr into a web app with faceting, tags etc. I was also evaluating haystack to see if that would provide a much better solution.

Is there a way to integrate existing solr index with haystack ? It looks like we need to create a model and populate the model and solr would index the model. But in my case, I already have the index built and just want to integrate into django through haystack. would appreciate any thoughts regarding this

thanks
Joe.